# Getting javascript var from database record in Smarty

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, prestashop

I'm working on a PrestaShop page with the file extension ".tpl". I get the javascript code to auto complete like this:

```
var currencies = [
{ value: 'Afghan afghani', data: 'AFN' },
{ value: 'Albanian lek', data: 'ALL' },
{ value: 'Algerian dinar', data: 'DZD' },
{ value: 'European euro', data: 'EUR' },
{ value: 'Angolan kwanza', data: 'AOA' },
{ value: 'East Caribbean dollar', data: 'XCD' },
{ value: 'Vietnamese dong', data: 'VND' },
{ value: 'Yemeni rial', data: 'YER' },
{ value: 'Zambian kwacha', data: 'ZMK' },
{ value: 'Zimbabwean dollar', data: 'ZWD' },];
```

While I also already have a `foreach` like the example below:

```
{foreach from=$currencies item=currency}
     {$currency.name}
     {$currency.code}
{/foreach}
```

How to output `currencies` value with `foreach`? I tried this code:

```
var currencies = [
{foreach from=$currencies item=currency}
   { value: '{$currency.name}', data: '{$currency.code}' },
{/foreach},];
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhYgL.jpg

Comment: I am not sure what you want here. Are you trying to change the database or what gets displayed?

Comment: I want to change this:
{ value: 'Afghan afghani', data: 'AFN' },
{ value: 'Albanian lek', data: 'ALL' },
{ value: 'Algerian dinar', data: 'DZD' },

like this:
{foreach from=$currencies item=currency}
{ value: '{$currency.name}', data: '{$currency.code}' },
{/foreach}

Comment: You are trying to build a json object and set it in the database? Or is this going to be displayed on a web page?

Comment: var currencies = [
{foreach from=$currencies item=currency}
   { value: '{$currency.name}', data: '{$currency.code}' },
{/foreach},];????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output a PHP array to JavaScript

This is the JavaScript code in the TPL

```
var currencies = JSON.parse('{$currencies|json_encode}');
```

`{$currencies|json_encode}` will output something like this

```
[{ value: 'Afghan afghani', data: 'AFN' },
{ value: 'Albanian lek', data: 'ALL' },
{ value: 'Algerian dinar', data: 'DZD' }, ...]
```

This output will be passed to the JavaScript function [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) which will transform the output string to a JavaScript object

Comment: Thank You for help. how to apply it to the function below?
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  lookup: currencies,
  onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.value???????? + ' <br> <strong>Symbol:</strong> ' + suggestion.data???????;
    $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i=0; i < currencies.length; i++) {
   newArray.push({value: whatever, data: whateverVar})
}
```

I am still not sure what you want but that is the best I can give from what I think you want.

Comment: I want to replace this values:
{ value: 'Afghan afghani', data: 'AFN' },
{ value: 'Albanian lek', data: 'ALL' },
{ value: 'Algerian dinar', data: 'DZD' },
with values from the database:
{ value: '{$currency.name}', data: '{$currency.code}' },

{$currency.name} and {$currency.code} taken from => {foreach}{$currency.name} and {$currency.code}{/foreach}

Bad English, sorry